# this.el(..).appendChild() is not a function error when calling client.draw()

Tags: keen-io

I'm trying to integrate the keen.io JS SDK with an angularJS application.  I don't have any trouble writing the events but I am having trouble drawing a chart.

I used the Explorer to generate the javascript for the chart, but have to make a couple modifications for it to be angular compatible.  Unfortunately when I get to the line actually calling client.draw (or in my case, keenClient.draw) I get an error thrown inside the keen.min.js file saying "this.el(..).appendChild() is not a function".

I am passing the actual div to the method and not just a text string, and I can see in the JS debugger that the div is being found.  The keenClient is also instantiated and the query seems to be created without error.  So I am not sure what is happening.  Here is what my controller looks like:

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view2', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
    controller: 'View2Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope, $document) {
   // write hit to keen
  var keenClient = new Keen({
    projectId: window.keenio_project_id, // String (required always)
    writeKey: window.keenio_write_key,   // String (required for sending data)
    readKey: window.keenio_read_key      // String (required for querying data)

    // protocol: "https",         // String (optional: https | http | auto)
    // host: "api.keen.io/3.0",   // String (optional)
    // requestType: "jsonp"       // String (optional: jsonp, xhr, beacon)
  });

    var pageHit = {
        "action": "loaded",
        "page": "view2"
    };

    keenClient.addEvent("pagehits", pageHit, function(err, res){
      if (err) {
          // there was an error!
          alert('Error sending keen.io stats');
      }
    });

     angular.element(Keen).ready(function (){

         var query = new Keen.Query("count", {
    eventCollection: "pagehits",
    groupBy: "page",
    interval: "hourly",
    timeframe: "this_3_days",
    timezone: "UTC"
  });

         var div = angular.element(document.getElementById("chart-wrapper"));

         keenClient.draw(query, div, 
             {
                 title: "Hits",
                 chartType: "columnchart"
             });

    });
}]);
```

My view is very simple:

```html
<div id="chart-wrapper" ng-controller="View2Ctrl"></div>
```

I am importing keen.io version 3.3.0, using angular 1.4.8.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.  I'm pretty new to angular as well as keen.io so I may be missing something silly here.

Answer (score 1):

After spending several hours troubleshooting I tried graphing with the Keen.Dataviz() option instead of client.draw() and that worked right away.  So I am thinking their simple syntax just is not Angular compatible.

```js
 var chart = new Keen.Dataviz() 
             .el(document.getElementById("chart-wrapper")) 
             .chartType("columnchart") 
             .prepare(); 
         var req = keenClient.run(query, function(err, res){ 
             if(err){ 
                 chart.err(err.message) 
             } 
             else{ 
                 chart.parseRequest(this).title("Hits").render(); 
             } 
         });  
        setInterval(function() { 
               req.refresh();
        }, 60000);
```

I still would be curious if anyone has a way to get the other syntax working, though I can do what I need this way.

Comment: i'm having all these same issues but couldn't come up with a working solution. do you have full source code of an example to share by chance? it seems like you've split the code between your question and answer which is confusing.